# Call nested rake file from the root directory

Tags: ruby, nested, rake

How can I run rake file for a nested project from the root directory? (2 cases: from console and from the root rakefile). Assume that I cannot modify the nested rakefile and that it must have 'libs/someproject' as the working directory.

Here is my project structure:

-root
 --rakefile.rb
 --libs
 ---someproject
 ----rakefile.rb

Comment: can you modify the root rakefile? If so then just add `require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'libs', 'someproject', 'rakefile.rb'))`

Comment: working directory should be 'libs/someproject/' for the nested rakefile, but it equals the root directory in your solution

Answer (score 2):

well, this is my current solution:

```
task :build_someproject do
  Dir.chdir 'libs/someproject' do
    system 'rake build'
  end
end
```